# Java: searching a string array from a CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, file-io

I am new at Java so please bear with me.

I need help for one of my assignments again. Now it involves FileI/O.

The task that I have to do is:

I have to read a .csv file. The values that's inside the file are:

```
Christopher Lee,54.0
Stanley Wright,90.5
Oliver Stewart,75.8
Jessica Chang,34.65
```

As the task said, I must store the contents on the file into two arrays. One for the names, and one for the test marks. I should read the file at least twice, once to check how many names are in the file and a couple more times to actually read the file (to get the names and marks). So basically, I should have an array to store the names as Strings, and an array to store the marks of the student as real numbers.

I should line up the arrays (e.g.students[0] should store the name of the first student and marks[0] should store the mark of the first student

After I stored the contents of the .csv file into an array I have to display a following menu to the user. If the user pressed 1, it should prompt the user to enter the name of a student. If the user pressed 2, the program should exit. If the name exists, it should display the test mark for the student entered. If the student does not exist then I must output a message indicating so to the user, yet the program should not end but return to the above menu.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = "file:///Documents/Java/marks_file.csv"; // Opens the file
    String[] arrayString = new String[6]; // String length inside the file
    int numLines, selection = 0;
    double[] arrayReal = new double[6]; // Number length inside the file
    numLines = getNumLines(fileName); // Gets the length of the file
    readFile(arrayString, arrayReal, fileName);

    // Selection menu
    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Select an option:");
        System.out.println("1. Display mark");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");
        selection = sc.nextInt();

        if (selection == 1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your full name");
            {
                // Do something
            }

        } 
        else if (selection == 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        }

    } 
    while (selection == 1);
    //System.out.println("Number of arrays: " + numLines);
}

// Method to get the length of the .csv file
public static int getNumLines(String fileName) 
{
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    String line;
    int lineNum = 0;
    try 
    {
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        line = bufRdr.readLine();

        while (line != null) 
        {
            lineNum = lineNum + 1;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
        }
        fileStrm.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (fileStrm != null) 
            {
                fileStrm.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex2) 
        {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return lineNum;
}
// Method to store the values to arrays
public static void readFile(String[] arrayString, double[] arrayReal, String fileName) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    String line;

    try 
    {
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++) 
        {
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            arrayString[i] = processString(line);
            arrayReal[i] = processReal(line);
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (fileStrm != null) 
            {
                fileStrm.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex2) 
        {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
// Stores the String lines to array
public static String processString(String line) 
{
    String string;
    String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
    return string = lineArray[0];
}

// Stores real number lines to array
public static double processReal(String line) 
{
    double real;
    String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
    return real = Double.parseDouble(lineArray[1]);
}
```

So far, I finished the "reading the file" part and processing the contents from a .csv file to an array.

I am not too sure how to prompt a user to search a string array from a .csv file. I tried looking at other sources, even at this website but I have no luck at all. I tried the Scanner.next() method but that doesn't work at all. Maybe I just missed something. Also, I am not sure if I did the "reading the file twice" right.

Am I on the right track? I am need of some guidance here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to say that I'd use a Map instead of two arrays but I'll show you a solution using two arrays.

You were close to the solution. One of you problems is that **scanner.next()** only reads the input until the first whitespace. That's why you need to use **scanner.nextLine()**. This method reads the complete line. And the code could look something like that:

---

## Solution with two arrays

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter name of student: ");
String name = sc.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++){
    if(name.equals(arrayString[i])) {
        System.out.println(arrayReal[i]);
    }
}
```

---

## Solution with a HashMap

1. Initialize HashMap

   `HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();`
2. Fill HashMap

   `hm.put("Christopher Lee", 54.0);`
3. Print double value of student

   `System.out.print("Please enter name of student: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(hm.get(name));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing into arrays, I would rather tell you to pass the data to data into generic arraylist and then query the result using get() method.

Comment: it seems like comment more than an answer. Please add some code atleast to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making simple thing difficult.

Just use a HashMap with name as the keys and test-score as the values.

1. You open file
2. You read each line and translate each line to an entry of hash map
3. When a text is input to the console, you just get it from hash map, if existed return the value, if not then back to number 3